# "I … like to watch cities and villages just drifting back"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I like traveling by train and like *to watch cities and villages just drifting back* when I look in the window from the upper foldable berth.

I ask if it is right in italics.

Comment: Not sure why you've bundled "when" into the same quoted part.  It starts another clause, "*when I look in the window...*"

Comment: BTW, it's better to say "*when I look **out** the window...*" rather than "***in***".

Comment: maybe "to watch cities and villages just drift back when i look out the window" or "cities and villages are just drifting back when i look out the window"

Comment: @VictorBazarov  - I don't think the OP meant for the quote to be split that way - it was edited.

Comment: "...just falling away" or "receding into the distance" are other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of that clause is

> ***I*** (subject)...***like*** (predicate) ***to watch ...*** (object) ***when I look...*** (adjunct)

Now, let's take the complex object and parse it further

> ...***to watch*** (verb) ***cities and ...*** (object of "*to watch*")

Further, still:

> ...***cities and villages*** (noun) ***just ...*** (adverbial phrase).

And, finally

> ...***just*** (adverb, related to '*drifting*') ***drifting back*** (present participle as adjective, from "*drift back*", prepositional verb).

Everything seems fine to me, honestly.  You can, of course, say "just drift back", which changes the structure of the objective clause slightly, giving it a **subject** and a **predicate** ('*drift back*'), but doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.